# Install a chocolatey "package" from its sources without packaging

Tags: chocolatey

Is it possible to install a chocolatey "package" from its sources without packaging (`choco pack`) it?

When developing a package we have the sources in a directory (or git repository). When testing we need to `choco pack` it before we `choco install`.

Is there a command to test-install the developed package without running `choco pack` before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

In order to use `choco install` you need to have a package to install so it needs to be created using the `choco pack` command. It takes seconds to run so it won't impact your workflow.

You could always run `choco pack; choco install <PACKAGENAME> --source .` from the folder containing the files, in a PowerShell session.

Comment: `choco pack` can take more than seconds when using internalized packages with big files.